# What is the best, easiest to integrate Java FOSS JTA lib?

Tags: java, jta

I am currently looking at JBoss Transactions and would like to hear about the experiences of others. I myself want something small, with few dependencies, few gotchas and follows standards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research looking around i have come across two packages which i believe are a possible solution for me:

- jboss tm
- jotm from objectweb

Currently i like JOTM simply because it is more document complete and easier to follow. I know that jboss-tm works as it provides the jta implementation used by the jboss a/sm but as someone getting started to integrate a jta implementation, jotm seems like the winner simply because its easier to get into.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to explore JPA(use EclipseLink or Hibernate to implement) in Glassfish or JBoss. It will give you best of both worlds Transaction and Relation Data mapping.

I hope I understood your query properly.

Comment: I don't think this was the question. He's looking for a JTA implementation. Hibernate/JPA builds on top of JTA, they don't implement it themselves.